# Predict sales with Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, data-science, prediction

I am a beginner in Python programming and machine learning.
I have a dataset with sales per product on monthly level.
The dataset has data from 2015 up till 2019.
With the help of Python I would like to make a prediction model that predicts the sales of the next month.

I followed this tutorial:
[Sales prediction](https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-sales-611cb5a252de)

This gave me a prediction of the last 6 months and lined them up with the actual sales, I managed to gat a pretty accurate prediction but my problem is that I need the predictions per product and if possible I would like to get the influence of weather in there aswell. For example if the weather data would be rainy it has to take this into account.

Does anyone know a way of doing this?
Every tip on which model to use or article to read is much appreciated!!

Comment: I think it isn't the best idea to start right away with a complicated deep learning approach like LSTM's if you're a beginner.
I'd suggest to try out different Regression-Techniques from Sklearn, which are much easier to understand.
If you want to consider weather aswell, you'd need to put a weather column into your dataset. You'd have to search if there's a dataset available that provides weather data for your time and place. Otherwise you can also check api's like openweathermap or something similar.

Comment: @raphael_mav Thanks for your reaction! is there a model you would recommend? I've read about ARIMA but never worked with it. Also, can I use regression with time series?

Comment: Just google for arima sklearn/sci-kit learn models and I'm sure you'll find lots of tutorials. Yes it's also possible to use regression techniques for time series data. Arima in fact is a regression technique suited for time-series data :)

Comment: @raphael_mav Thankyou, I will try ARIMA! do you know a way to easily make predictions per product instead of the totals per month. And having the weather data in a column, how would I use this to influence the prediction?

Comment: I didn't read the tutorial, so I can't tell you exactly but you split your data into a feature and a target part. You train your model to predict the target part. If your target contains the information about total sales you also will get predictions about total sales. To get predictions for each product you need to change your dataset accordingly. Regarding the weather data, if you have the weather data in your dataset your model will use this information anyway to learn how to predict the output.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read about Linear Regression since it's easy to understand - that is a good start to get a feeling for how different features influence the output of the model :)

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way of doing that would be to run an ARIMA model with external regressors (the weather measured in terms of temperature, humidity or any other feature that is expected to influence the monthly sales).
What is important is that before fitting the model, the sales data had better be transformed into log monthly changes by something like `np.log(df.column).diff()`.
I've recently written a Python micro-package `salesplansuccess`, which deals with prediction of the current (or next) year's annual sales for individual products from historic monthly sales data. But a major assumption for that model is a quarterly seasonality (more specifically a repeating drift from the 2nd to the 3rd month in each quarter), which is more characteristic for wholesalers (who strives to achieve their formal quarterly sales goals by pushing sales at the end of each quarter).
The package is installed as usual with `pip install salesplansuccess`.
You can modify its source code for it to better fit your needs. It uses both ARIMA (maximum likelihood estimates) and linear regression (least square estimates) technics under the hood.
The minimalistic use case is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
from salesplansuccess.api import SalesPlanSuccess
myHistoricalData = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')
myAnnualPlan = 1000
sps = SalesPlanSuccess(data=myHistoricalData, plan=myAnnualPlan)
sps.fit()
sps.simulate()
sps.plot()
```

For more detailed illustration of its use, you may want to refer to a Jupyter Notebook illustration [file](https://github.com/yuryatin/salesplansuccess/blob/main/salesplansuccess_illustration.ipynb) at its GitHub [repository](https://github.com/yuryatin/salesplansuccess).